# Resumable Media Upload with the Google API Java Client library stops at 90%

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I try to enable the "Resumable Media Upload" with the Google API Java Client library;

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload

But my uploads stops every time between 90 en 100% ... Does anybody know whats going wrong?

Comment: Weird, any more info or errors? Thanks.

Comment: Yes Ali; the problem is the ContentLength of the received stream. I used getRequest().getContentLength() but this is not correct because this is the complete request and not only the document stream. I posted this problem as a new question on stackoverflow;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234028/how-do-i-determine-the-stream-size-from-an-uploaded-file-from-a-website-which-i

Comment: I have similar problem but in my case the IOException "insufficient data written" is thrown.