# How do i determine the stream size from an uploaded file from a website which i want to insert in Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-drive-api, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm trying to upload files to Google Drive with *ProgressListener* and *ChunkSize* enabled (thus with *DirectUploadEnabled* disabled). This way i have a more reliable upload and the possibility for a progress indication to the user.

I transfer the files from the GWT website to the GAE with a FormPanel and a FileUploadField which POSTS the file to GAE on submit(). On the GAE i receive the file with an UploadServlet which uses *org.apache.commons.fileupload* to receive the documents as a stream. I don't want to receive the complete documents on the GAE because the documents are to big. Therefore i start the upload (insert) to Google Drive with the received stream from the incoming request.

Now there's a problem; for the insert i need to know the size of the stream;

```
int lContentLength = getRequest().getContentLength();
FileItemStream lFileItemStream = getFileItemStream();
InputStream lInputStream = lFileItemStream.openStream();
BufferedInputStream lBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(lInputStream);
InputStreamContent lInputStreamContent = new InputStreamContent(pContentType, lBufferedInputStream);
lInputStreamContent.setLength(lContentLength);
```

My first guess was the *ContentLengt* from the incoming Servlet request. But this is not correct because this concerns the complete request (which also contains other fields which are used as parameters). Without the Drive option *DirectUploadEnabled* i need the exact stream size from the uploaded document, otherwise the upload stall's at the end...

How do i grap this document size? The Google example is stupid because it uses a local file;

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/MediaUpload

Yes from a local file it is easy to get the file size *(mediaFile.length())*. But from a website ... Several sites specify it is not possible to grab the file size before submit() from the website, and it seems also impossible to determine the stream-size on GAE without loading the complete file...

How do i determine this streamsize? Is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063164/google-drive-inputstreamcontent-requires-length-to-be-set][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063164/google-drive-inputstreamcontent-requires-length-to-be-set

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=591